# Calculating average of a set of numbers without postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, real-time, average

I need to enter a set of numbers in a textbox in this form 12, 13, 54, 12 and calculate the average of the numbers from the textbox.

Is their any form or something with javascript or jquery to calculate this on realtime or without post back.

Thanks

Comment: you could use js onkeyup event and put the result next to the textfield

Comment: wats wrong wth using regex and getting those numbers and calculating average for them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#yourtextbox").keyup(function(){
           var text = $(this).val();
           var arr = text.split(',');

           var sum = 0;
           var count = 0;
           $.each(arr,function(index,value){
               var currentItem = parseInt(value);
               if (!isNaN(currentItem)){
                  sum+= currentItem;
                  count++;
               }
           });

           console.log(sum/count);
           $("#result").text(sum/count);
        });
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qwxh4/2/)

Comment: tnx for the code but how can I display this answer in another textbox or label pls tnx

Comment: yes my bad it works...how can I show that in a textbox please? the result

Comment: @Mark Fenech: check my updated answer. I display it in a span. You can do it similarly for textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.x').keyup(function(){
var total = 0;
$('.x').each(function()
{
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());    
    if(!isNaN(value))
        total += value;
})
alert(total);})
```

I saved a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hcs49/; instead of using class selector, you could also use input[type=text]